# Xamarin getting Wrong item when clicking and longItemClick listview c# vs2017

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

when filtering data and LongItemClick I get wrong data, also when I click ItemClick also 
wrong data.
Can we help me?

What I need change to works fine?

I send Model,Activity and Adapter.

There is my Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

 namespace NovaAndroid.Model
{
 public class the_SetSubjModel
 {

    public string acSubject { get; set; }


    public string acAddress { get; set; }


    public string acName2 { get; set; }


    public string acPost { get; set; }


    public string acCountry { get; set; }


    public string acCode { get; set; }


    public string acPhone { get; set; }


    public string acRegNo { get; set; }


    public decimal anRebate { get; set; }


    public string acBuyer { get; set; }


    public static explicit operator the_SetSubjModel(Java.Lang.Object v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

There is My Adapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using NovaAndroid.Model;

namespace NovaAndroid.Adapters
{
[Activity(Label = "ContactListBaseAdapter")]
public partial class ContactListBaseAdapter : BaseAdapter<the_SetSubjModel>
{

    IList<the_SetSubjModel> contactListArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context activity;     


    public ContactListBaseAdapter(Context context, IList<the_SetSubjModel> 
 results)
    {
        this.activity = context;          

        contactListArrayList = results;
        mInflater = 
(LayoutInflater)activity.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return contactListArrayList.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override the_SetSubjModel this[int position]
    {
        get { return contactListArrayList[position]; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
```

I think there is problem in GetView method?
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
    parent)
        {

```
        ContactsViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = 
 mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_row_contact_list, null);
            holder = new ContactsViewHolder();
            // Show item in listView
            holder.txtacSubject = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> 
 (Resource.Id.lr_fullName);
            holder.txtacAddress = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> 
(Resource.Id.lr_address);
            holder.txtEmail = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> 
(Resource.Id.lr_email);
            holder.txtPib = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> 
(Resource.Id.lr_pib);              

            convertView.Tag = holder;             

        }
        else
        {              
            holder = convertView.Tag as ContactsViewHolder;                
        }

        holder.txtacSubject.Text = 
contactListArrayList[position].acSubject.ToString();
        holder.txtacAddress.Text = contactListArrayList[position].acAddress;
        holder.txtEmail.Text = contactListArrayList[position].acPost;
        holder.txtPib.Text = contactListArrayList[position].acCode;


        if (position % 2 == 0)
        {

convertView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.list_selector);
        }
        else
        {

convertView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.list_selector_alternate);
        }           

        return convertView;

    }       

        public IList<the_SetSubjModel> GetAllData()
    {
        return contactListArrayList;
    }

    public class ContactsViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView txtacSubject { get; set; }
        public TextView txtacAddress { get; set; }
        public TextView txtEmail { get; set; }
        public TextView txtPib { get; set; }            
        public TextView txtacName2 { get; set; }
        public TextView txtacPhone { get; set; }
        public TextView txtacRegNo { get; set; }
        public TextView txtanRebate { get; set; }
    }

    class ContactListBaseAdapterViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        //Your adapter views to re-use
        //public TextView Title { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

There is My Activity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using NovaAndroid.Model;
using NovaAndroid.Adapters;
using Android.Views;

namespace NovaAndroid
{
[Activity(Label = "Svi kupci", MainLauncher = false)]
public class ToDoItemActivity : Activity
{
    //Button btnAdd;
    private SearchView sv;
    private ListView lista;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    IList<the_SetSubjModel> listaToDo = null;
    List<the_SetSubjModel> readed = new List<the_SetSubjModel>();
    the_SetSubjModel model = new the_SetSubjModel();
    EditText  contactList_txtSearch;
    Button btnHomeScreen;

    private const string URL = 
"http://192.168.147.10:8888/Service.svc/GetAllSubjectWithoutBuyer";

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ToDoItemView);

        btnHomeScreen = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonHome);
        btnHomeScreen.Click += BtnHomeScreen_Click;
        GetAllSubjectWithoutBuyer();          

        var str = readed.Select(x => x.acSubject).ToList();

        var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

        contactList_txtSearch = FindViewById<EditText> 
(Resource.Id.contactList_txtSearch);

        lista = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView);
        lista.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, str);

        lista = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
        sv = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, str);
        lista.Adapter = adapter;

        listaToDo = readed;

        contactList_txtSearch.TextChanged += 
ContactList_txtSearch_TextChanged;     

        lista.ItemClick += Lista_ItemClick;

        lista.ItemLongClick += Lista_ItemLongClick;

        //
        lista.Adapter = new ContactListBaseAdapter(this, listaToDo);

    }       

    private void BtnHomeScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var activityHome = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(activityHome);
    }

    private void GetAllSubjectWithoutBuyer()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        //request.ContentLength = DATA.Length;

        try
        {
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var json = 

  webClient.DownloadString("http://192.168.147.10:8888/
Service.svc/GetAllSubjectWithoutBuyer");
                SResult web = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SResult>(json);
                readed = web.GetAllSubjectWithoutBuyerResult;

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

private void ContactList_txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, 
Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var searchText = contactList_txtSearch.Text;

        //Compare the entered text with List  
        List<the_SetSubjModel> list = (from items in readed
                                    where 
items.acCode.Contains(contactList_txtSearch.Text)

                                    select items).ToList<the_SetSubjModel>();

        lista.Adapter = new ContactListBaseAdapter(this,list);
        this.lista.DeferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    }      

    private void Lista_ItemLongClick(object sender, 
AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        the_SetSubjModel o = readed[e.Position];
        var activityAddEdit = new Intent(this, typeof(AddEditActivity));
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("acSubject", o.acSubject.ToString());
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("acAddress", o.acAddress.ToString());
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("acPost", o.acPost.ToString());
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("acCode", o.acCode.ToString());
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("acCountry", o.acCountry.ToString());
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("acName2", o.acName2.ToString());
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("acPhone", o.acPhone.ToString());
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("acRegNo", o.acRegNo.ToString());
        activityAddEdit.PutExtra("anRebate", o.anRebate.ToString());
        StartActivity(activityAddEdit);
    }

    private void Lista_ItemClick(object sender, 
AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, adapter.GetItem(e.Position).ToString(), 
ToastLength.Short).Show();

    }  

}
```

Picture example ItemClick wrong:

[image]

Comment: error is obvious: lets say we have array `a1 = {a, b, c}` and filtered array  `a1'= { a, c }` ... if you "click" on item `c` with `a1'` you will get position `1`(zero-based) .... and now if you are use this position with `a1` you will get `b` ... the solution is ... right `BaseAdapter` implementation - `GetItem` should return a right item - not position

Comment: Yes. it is necessary to return the right item, just how to do it. Can the code be sent?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your own question, as if you are inheriting from base adapter you need to implement the GetView() method in your adapter if you want to create a layout inflater.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i fix for item "click" I get the right values.
But tell me how to use LongClick ? and get values for that item in new form?
This is new code for BaseAdapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using NovaAndroid.Model;

namespace NovaAndroid.Adapters
{
[Activity(Label = "ContactListBaseAdapter")]
public partial class ContactListBaseAdapter : BaseAdapter<the_SetSubjModel>
{

    IList<the_SetSubjModel> contactListArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context activity;
    the_SetSubjModel model = new the_SetSubjModel();
    Dictionary<int, the_SetSubjModel> items;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mRowLayout;


    public ContactListBaseAdapter(Context context, IList<the_SetSubjModel> results, 
int rowLayout) 
    {
        this.activity = context;
        this.items = items;
        context = context;
        mContext = context;
        mRowLayout = rowLayout;
        contactListArrayList = results;
        mInflater = 
 (LayoutInflater)activity.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return contactListArrayList.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override the_SetSubjModel this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }



    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }



    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View view = convertView;
        if(view==null)
        {
           // view = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(mRowLayout, parent, 
  false);
            //view = Layou   // view = 
  context.tInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(mRowLayout, parent, false);
            //view = 
  LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_row_contact_list, null);
        }
        //ImageView btnDelete;
        //ContactsViewHolder holder = null;

            view = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_row_contact_list, null);
            //holder = new ContactsViewHolder();
            //// Show item in listView
            //holder.txtacSubject = view.FindViewById<TextView> 
 (Resource.Id.lr_fullName);
            //holder.txtacAddress = view.FindViewById<TextView> 
 (Resource.Id.lr_address);
            //holder.txtEmail = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lr_email);
            //holder.txtPib = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lr_pib);



            //view.Tag = holder;





        TextView txtacSubject = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lr_fullName);
        txtacSubject.Text = contactListArrayList[position].acSubject;

        TextView txtacAddress = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lr_address);
        txtacAddress.Text = contactListArrayList[position].acAddress;

        TextView txtEmail = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lr_email);
        txtEmail.Text = contactListArrayList[position].acPost;

        TextView txtPib = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lr_pib);
        txtPib.Text = contactListArrayList[position].acCode;


        if (position % 2 == 0)
        {
            view.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.list_selector);
        }
        else
        {
            view.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.list_selector_alternate);
        }

        view.Click += delegate
          {
              Toast.MakeText(mContext, contactListArrayList[position].acSubject, 
        ToastLength.Short).Show();
          };

        view.LongClick += delegate
          {

          };


        return view;


    }



    public IList<the_SetSubjModel> GetAllData()
    {
        return contactListArrayList;
    }

    public class ContactsViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView txtacSubject { get; set; }
        public TextView txtacAddress { get; set; }
        public TextView txtEmail { get; set; }
        public TextView txtPib { get; set; }            
        public TextView txtacName2 { get; set; }
        public TextView txtacPhone { get; set; }
        public TextView txtacRegNo { get; set; }
        public TextView txtanRebate { get; set; }


    }

    class ContactListBaseAdapterViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        //Your adapter views to re-use
        //public TextView Title { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

This is My new form where i must show data for I  Long"click" item

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NovaAndroid.Model;

namespace NovaAndroid
{
[Activity(Label = "Prikaz detalja kupci")]
public class AddEditActivity : Activity
{
    EditText txtacSubject, txtacAddress, txtEmail, 
txtPib,txtCountry,txtName,txtPhone,txtacRegNo,txtanRebate;
    Button btnBack;

    the_SetSubjModel model = new the_SetSubjModel();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AddEditToDoItem);

        txtacSubject = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_acSubject);
        txtacAddress = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_address);
        txtEmail = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_email);
        txtPib = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_PIB);
        txtCountry= FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_acCountry);
        txtName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_acName2);
        txtPhone = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_acPhone);
        txtacRegNo = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_acRegNo);
        txtanRebate = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addEdit_anRebate);
        btnBack = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addEdit_btnBack);

        btnBack.Click += BtnBack_Click; 

        string acSubject = Intent.GetStringExtra("acSubject") ?? 
string.Empty;
        string acAddress = Intent.GetStringExtra("acAddress") ?? 
string.Empty;
        string editMail = Intent.GetStringExtra("acPost") ?? string.Empty;
        string editPib = Intent.GetStringExtra("acCode") ?? string.Empty;
        string editCountry = Intent.GetStringExtra("acCountry") ?? 
string.Empty;
        string editacName2 = Intent.GetStringExtra("acName2") ?? 
string.Empty;
        string editacPhone = Intent.GetStringExtra("acPhone") ?? 
string.Empty;
        string editacRegNo = Intent.GetStringExtra("acRegNo") ?? 
string.Empty;
        string editanRebate = Intent.GetStringExtra("anRebate") ?? 
string.Empty;
        if (acSubject.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            txtacSubject.Text = acSubject;
            txtacAddress.Text = acAddress;
            txtEmail.Text = editMail;
            txtPib.Text = editPib;
            txtCountry.Text = editCountry;
            txtName.Text = editacName2;
            txtPhone.Text = editacPhone;
            txtacRegNo.Text = editacRegNo;
            txtanRebate.Text = editanRebate;

        }
    }

    private void BtnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var activityBack = new Intent(this, typeof(ToDoItemActivity));
        StartActivity(activityBack);
    }


}


}
```